# usb x-x: device not accepting address XX, error -32

Tags: linux, usb, fedora, kernel, kernel-messages

since quite some time and across distribution updates (fedora 21-24) and kernel updates (now 4.5.7-300.fc24.x86_64) my system endlessly produces the following messages in the system-log (which is also displayed in the terminal with ctrl-alt-F1 every 1 seconds)

```
message: usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number XX using ehci-pci   
kernel device: +usb:1-1.1

message: usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32   
kernel device: +usb:1-1.1


message: usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address XX, error -32    
kernel device: +usb:1-1.1
```

and then we start over with the first message. cycle duration is about 1-2 secs, so my log is literally filled with these messages.

`lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0     
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub    
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation     
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0c45:644f Microdia     
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card     Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation     
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation     
Bus 003 Device 028: ID 046d:c00e Logitech, Inc. M-BJ58/M-BJ69 Optical Wheel Mouse    
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation
```

I have no idea what this error message means (since I'm not aware of any non-working usb devices), nor what device is producing the error. can someone point me towards a solution of this problem?

Comment: Same issue here. I guess that it happens  when you have a low speed USB which the system tries to assign to a high speed USB list. It doesn't seem to affect the functionality of the port though.

Comment: actually, in my case, this may not be the explanation, as my system does not feature USB1 ports at all.

it may be the other way around, though? Despite me never noticing some speed degradation in USB devices

Comment: I'm receiving that error when I try to plug my USB MIDISPORT 2x2. I installed the package midisport-firmware. I can't make it work, that is why I'm searching the Internet and found this related question here.